Why text colors are not working in Xiaomi 12T
The text in totalizador1TextView, do not change according with instruction, allways black. MIUI Global 14.0.13   Android 13TP1A
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources>     <style name="MeuTema" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/amarelo_torrado</item>         <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/encarnado</item>         <item name="colorAccent">@color/verde</item>         <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>         <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>         <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>     </style> </resources>

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO); 
..... 
.....  
.....
totalizador1TextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.amarelo));  


Try this one instead:
totalizador1TextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.amarelo,null))

